Get token from the node js lambda function
I developed a nodejs code in my lambda function that retrieve token from AWS.
I succeed to get token, but when I am using this token to request any endpoint I got 401 Unauthorized.
I decoded it with JWT and I got:
{
  "sub": "*****",
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-*****",
  "client_id": "*****",
  "origin_jti": "*****",
  "event_id": "******",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
  "auth_time": 1719906953,
  "exp": 1719910553,
  "iat": 1719906953,
  "jti": "*****",
  "username": "*****"
}

with postman I am getting the following token
{
  "sub": "*****",
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-*****",
  "version": 2,
  "client_id": "*****",
  "origin_jti": "*****",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid mpfapi/fullaccess email",
  "auth_time": 1719917974,
  "exp": 1719921574,
  "iat": 1719917974,
  "jti": "*****",
  "username": "*****"
}

if I use the token retrieved from my nodejs code then AWS will return 401
if I use the token retrieved from postman then it works
here after my nodejs source code:
const getSecretHash = (username, clientId, clientSecret) => {
    return crypto.createHmac('SHA256', clientSecret)
        .update(username + clientId)
        .digest('base64');
};
const authenticateUser = async (username, password) => {
    const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: RYSEregion });
    const secretHash = getSecretHash(username, poolData.ClientId, poolData.ClientSecret);

    const params = {
        AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters: {
            'USERNAME': username,
            'PASSWORD': password,
            'SECRET_HASH': secretHash
        },
        ClientId: poolData.ClientId
    };

    try {
        const command = new InitiateAuthCommand(params);
        const response = await client.send(command);
        return response.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

the postman use as config:

Auth type: OAuth 2.0
Grant type: Authorization code

EDIT:
I think the cause of the issue is : the auth used in postman is using redirect web page URL to enter username/pass
and then it’s triggering Host UI in cognito:

and the node hs auth function in my lambda function is using anther interface/way which is not the same of Hosted UI
that’s why I am not getting the same scopes
and I can’t find another interface to add scope in cognito
what I am missing ?

The big difference between the two is the "scope" parameters.  You should ensure that you're requesting the correct scopes.
not working:
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"

working:
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid mpfapi/fullaccess email"


these scopes are defined in my cognito. I am not adding them in Postman neither in my nodejs code

There's clearly a difference in the service you're using then.

I am using same client ID, client secret, pool ID....
Just the AUTH Flow I am using USER_PASSWORD_AUTH in the nodejs
and may be postman is using other thing since I al connecting via web redirect url
how I can check the service for each one ?

Question edited
